# PHP JSON read object attribute

Tags: php, json, file

I am a beginner in php rogramming and I try to get some information per PHP out of an JSON string. 
Therefore I used:

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json')
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

to get more information how php will parse my JSON file. Output of it looks like:

```
array(10) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (1) { 
    ["links"]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (6) { 
            ["localIP"]=> string(14) "172.29.126.189" 
            ["remoteIP"]=> string(14) "172.29.118.193" 
            ["validityTime"]=> int(586277) 
            ["linkQuality"]=> float(1) 
            ["neighborLinkQuality"]=> float(0.396) 
            ["linkCost"]=> float(2.524) } 

        [1]=> object(stdClass)#3 (6) { 
            ["localIP"]=> string(14) "172.29.126.189" 
            ["remoteIP"]=> string(14) "172.29.149.193" 
            ["validityTime"]=> int(551339) 
            ["linkQuality"]=> float(1) 
            ["neighborLinkQuality"]=> float(0.396) 
            ["linkCost"]=> float(2.524) } } } }
...
```

I want to know how I would be able to display for example:

- the "remoteIP" Attribute of Links[0]
- all Attributes of Links[0]

Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: try json_decode($json,true); .... that way all the json will be represented as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have an array, you use square brackets to access any index of it. Whenever you have an object, you use the `->` operator to access a property of it.

So for your examples, it would be:

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json');
$data = json_decode($json);

var_dump($data[0]->links[0]->remoteIP); // remoteIP of links[0]
var_dump($data[0]->links[0]); // All attributes of links[0], as object
```

Another way would be (as Leo Bali pointed out), to let PHP convert all objects to arrays. In that case, you always use square brackets:

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json');
$data = json_decode($json, true); // Add true here as second parameter

var_dump($data[0]['links'][0]['remoteIP']); // remoteIP of links[0]
var_dump($data[0]['links'][0]); // All attributes of links[0], as array
```